# TCPListener in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, tcplistener

I am trying to write a TCP listener that can connect to multiple clients and send and receive data.
Some of my code -

Calling server -

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cresijCamDataSet1.CentralControl' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.centralControlTableAdapter1.Fill(this.cresijCamDataSet1.CentralControl);

         s = new Server();
        Thread th = new Thread(s.Run);
        th.Start();
    }
```

Run Method -

```
public async void Run()
    {
         tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1200);

        tcp.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = await tcp.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                Thread th = new Thread(()=>{
                   Process(client);
                  }) ;   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string m = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

private async Task Process(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {

            bool hasItem = clients.Contains(tcpClient);
            if(hasItem == false)
            {
                clients.Add(tcpClient);
            }
            IPEndPoint iPEndPoint =(IPEndPoint) tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

            string ip = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];


            stream.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length);

                f.UpdateData(receivedBytes, ip);
 }
```

Sender Method to send data -

```
 public void Sender(byte[] data, TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        }
```

As you can see I have called Run() method in formLoad. But this all is not working as I dont have much knowledge of threads.

This method is not continuous. The server is not listening to clients always. Can someone help me with this. I need asynchronuous tcp listener that can listen to incoming clients and that too in windows form. Console Server I have.

Comment: Two things definitely not helping you here - you're completely silently swallowing any exceptions generated in your `Run` method and you're ignoring the return value from `Read`.

Comment: have a look at the [return value of Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) => "The number of bytes read from the NetworkStream, or 0 if the socket is closed."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever.. during debug... Its not showing any exception in Run()... I wanted the data from read that I am getting into receivedBytes..

Comment: Edited: `int count= stream.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length);
            if(count>0)
            {
                f.UpdateData(receivedBytes, ip);
            }
            
            else
            {
                tcpClient.Close();
                clients.Remove(tcpClient);
            }`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever.. Its saying Process() is not a async method because I am not using await keyword inside it. But I really dont need await in that for now or I dont know where to use await in there

Comment: `ReadAsync` instead of `Read` would be the obvious change to introduce an await point. But you still seem to be missing the point - `count` tells you *how many* bytes of `receivedBytes` are valid. You're then passing the *entire* array to `UpdateData`. You either need to resize your array or pass this count information into `UpdateData`.

Comment: what is the value of `tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize` ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever.. It was 8192.. Just changed it to 20 as that will be the max I will receive from client device

Comment: All that you're guaranteed from any particular call to `Read` is *1*. Even if someone at the other end called `Write` with a 20 byte buffer. TCP is *stream of bytes*, not *messages*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever.. ok.. So you are saying I should increase the size so that there should be less chance of issues regarding that